# Blender cloth sinking into basket

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to model a low poly picnic basket, and I want to put a cloth into it like this (so the cloth goes into the middle):
[image]

When I use default cloth settings I get this:
[image]

[image: the cloth lays like this:]

what settings/techniques can I use to try to get the effect of the cloth loosely lining the basket? thanks in advance!

Comment: I managed to get the effect by manually moving the vertices down, but if anyone knows a better way please let me know! :)

Comment: If this is for a static shot / passive model / you can't see internal creases .. that sounds the way to go. Be lazy. Avoid further simulation if you don't need it :)

Answer (score 1):

this effect can be achieved if you reduce the cloth bending stiffness

physics properties > stiffness>bending

you can also animate the sphere to stuff the cloth inside